# RabbitMQ dead letter queue delayed messages

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

We are using RabbitMQ dead letter queue to get messages from a queue at the certain time. But, sometimes the message is received after a long time delay. We are not able to get the root cause of this. The Message should be received instantly as soon as the timer is expired.

Here is the example code

```
using (var channel = _connection.CreateModel())
{
    var queueArgs = new Dictionary<string, object> {
        { "x-dead-letter-exchange", workExchangeName}
    };

    channel.ExchangeDeclare(retryExchangeName, "direct", true, false, null);
    channel.QueueDeclare(retryQueueName, true, false, false, queueArgs);
    channel.QueueBind(retryQueueName, retryExchangeName, routingKey, null);

    var body = Utility.SerializeSoapObject(message);

    var messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);

    IBasicProperties properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
    properties.Expiration = timeout; -- Time-out in milliseconds

    channel.BasicPublish(retryExchangeName, routingKey, properties, messageBytes);
}
```

Comment: Girish, can you show more source of code.